# how to set width of cloned tr th's for fixed table headings

Tags: jquery, html, css

The end goal is to create "sticky" column headings which move out of the way once the next heading hits the top of the window. 
I have taken a look online and have found at least 4 or 5 plugins which all appear to be `thead` based and not `tr th`.

So far I have a large table which is divided into sections, each with a row of `th`. 
I have used jQuery to clone each of the `tr` elements into a new table which is positioned at the top of the window.

Next, I fixed the position of each `tr` so that each row is stacked. The problem I have encountered is when setting the width. I have been able to set the with of the `tr` but when I am trying to get and set the cloned `th` based on the original, its just not working.

There is a LOT of code to see this working, I'll include the jQuery as that is what I need help with, there is also a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/NQNt7/

```
(function () {
    var tableWrapper = $('<div />').attr({ id: 'fakeTableWrapper' }),
        newTable = $('<table />').attr({ id: 'fakeTable', 'class': 'rpt' }).css({ 'table-layout': 'fixed' });

    $('#page').prepend(tableWrapper) 
    $('#fakeTableWrapper').prepend(newTable);

})();

 $('tr.tabHead').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        w = $this.innerWidth() + 'px',
        copy = $this.clone(),

        $tableBodyCell = $('tr.tabHead:first td'),
        $headerCell = copy.children('th');

    copy.removeAttr('class');
    copy.children('th').removeAttr('data-coltype');
    copy.children('th').removeAttr('data-col');
    copy.children('th').removeAttr('class');
    copy.children('th').removeAttr('style');

    //THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING, TRYING TO SET THE CLONE TH
    $tableBodyCell.each(function (index) {
        copy.children('th').removeAttr('style');
        $headerCell.eq(index).width($(this).width());
    });     

    $('#fakeTable tr').css({ 'width': w });

        $('#fakeTable').append(copy);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to achieve, it looks like it's just a selector problem. There's no `td` having a `tr` with class `tabHead` as its parent, so the code is not entering the `$tableBodyCell.each` loop.

Replace the `td`:

```
$tableBodyCell = $('tr.tabHead:first td')
```

With `th`:

```
$tableBodyCell = $('tr.tabHead:first th')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NQNt7/5/

Comment: What a mistake to make! @MelanciaUK thank you for pointing that out.